# How to select a huge string variable in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So I have this huge line-by-line std::string variable which is about 58 thousand lines.
How could I select my entire variable? By clicking and dragging I think it takes about 5 minutes :)

This is how I stored my string:

```
std::string str = "504b0304140000000800b3ab584fd82c4d1ec01b00002a45000007000000"
                  "4348414e474553955bfb73db4872fed95775ffc364cf1593673e44ca92bd"
                  "aa3b27b6a4f5ea4eaf58f2de6ea5121c080c499cf03a0c2089fbd7a7bfee"
                  "...";
```

It goes for about 58 thousand lines, how could I select it?

Comment: Select it? You mean like select it with your mouse? Anyway a string that big should be stored in a file which your program can read, instead of stored in source code.

Comment: Having selected it, what do you plan to do with it?

Comment: I want it as a global variable inside my code files. But I was wondering if there is a way to select it entirely...?

Comment: It seems there is no alternative but to store it in an exclusive file.

Comment: @PaulSanders I had this inside of a .cpp file and I wanted to remove it. But by hitting Ctrl+A the whole file and my codes would be deleted.

Comment: I would copy the file, open it with Vim on Linux and remove everything else. Vim has optimizations that allow to open and work with large files. I remember a team that had to send their log files to Linux users because Windows froze with very large files.

Comment: You should be able to click the front of the string, then navigate to the end of the string by clicking/dragging on scroll bar, and shift+click the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks @Ranoiaetep. That was the answer that I was looking for...

Comment: Could also stick `#if 0` at one end and `#endif` at the other.  But I guess that ship has sailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to select my huge variable by clicking at the beginning of my variable and `Shift+click` at the end of it. (@Ranoiaetep idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Expand Selection" by `Ctrl + Alt + right arrow/arrow`